# Reflexivity axiom for inferring functional dependencies

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, functional-dependencies

As you know, there are three [Armstrong's Axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) for inferring all the functional dependencies on a relational database. (X, Y and Z are set of attributes)

1. **Reflexivity**: *If X ⊆ Y, then Y → X*
2. **Augmentation**: *If X → Y, then XZ → YZ for any Z*
3. **Transitivity**: *if X → Y and Y → Z, then X → Z*

I understand the augmentation and transitivity for example if we had such schema:

> SOME_SCHEMA(a, b, c, d)

with such functional dependencies:

> 1. a → b
> 2. b → c

By using augmentation we could get *ac → bc* or by using transitivity we could get *a → c* and much more, however I am not sure how to infer more functional dependencies using reflexivity axiom? What does it really mean that some attribute is a subset of some other attribute?

Could you show me an example using my schema or creating your own, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transitivty rule can be also stated like this:

```
A1, A2, …, An → Ai
```

Where i is any number between 1 and n.  I think this definition of the rule is a bit clearer. A1 is a subset of A1 through An, and thus you can infer the above dependency.

These type of dependencies are called trivial dependencies.  The simplest form of this is:

```
A → A
```

As you can see, A is a subset of A, therefore by the definition of reflexivity, we can infer the above dependency.

This really isn't a very useful axiom, both of the first two axioms are not very useful on their own, but are there for formality sake, so we can get to the last axiom, which is very useful.

To use your example, we could say the following.  Given that we have the table:

```
SOME_SCHEMA(a, b, c, d)
```

We can infer such dependencies as:

```
a, b, c, d → a
a, b, c, d → a, c
```

And many more dependencies of the same nature.

By the way, here are some good slides that explain functional dependencies in general really well.  There a few slides on Armstrong's rules as well.  I found these helpful when learning this stuff: [Functional Dependency Slides](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse344/12au/lectures/lecture16-design-theory.pdf)

Comment: Given that the Reflexivity axiom says: If X ⊆ Y, then Y → X, does that not mean that if Y = {a,b}, then the axiom only holds if X = {a} OR X = {b}, and not if X = Y?

X ⊆ Y means "if X is a proper subset of Y", and a proper subset of Y can by definition not be the same as Y. I'm only asking because I'm up for exam in a few days :)

Comment: @UltromantheTacoman ⊆ means subset (proper subset or equal), not proper subset; traditionally in math ⊂ means the same thing, but in a context with both we would expect ⊂ to be explicitly defined as proper.